# PHP Bcrypt hashing

Tags: php, hash, pear, blowfish, crypt

I want to use **Blowfish hashing** to hash password.

`crypt()` does not support it in PHP versions prior to 5.3

My PHP version is 5.2.14. How can I use Blowfish hashing? Can I use PEAR's `Crypt_Blowfish` instead?

Comment: Isn't blowfish for encryption and not hashing?

Comment: He means bcrypt that is a password derivation scheme using some Blowfish parts.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you use bcrypt for hashing passwords in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4795385/how-do-you-use-bcrypt-for-hashing-passwords-in-php)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PEAR's Crypt_Blowfish is meant to stand in for PHP's MCrypt extension - it's a *two-way* encryption scheme, not for hashing. While bcrypt is based on Blowfish, it's not the same thing. Confusingly, PHP 5.3.0's CRYPT_BLOWFISH is a hashing algorithm.

Is there a reason why upgrading to PHP 5.3.0+ would not be possible? This isn't something you want to try to implement yourself. If you can, [phpass](http://www.openwall.com/phpass/) is a great way to do bcrypt-based password hashing securely. If you absolutely can't upgrade, phpass falls back to older hashing schemes (but it's still more secure than plain MD5, etc).

If for some reason you can install [Suhosin](http://www.hardened-php.net/suhosin/) but not upgrade PHP, that would add CRYPT_BLOWFISH support.

To make sure you don't currently have CRYPT_BLOWFISH installed, try the following:

```
 echo (CRYPT_BLOWFISH === 1) ? 'CRYPT_BLOWFISH is enabled!' : 'CRYPT_BLOWFISH is not available';
```

Comment: To clarify... the php [`crypt()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php) function, which can be set up to use the [`CRYPT_BLOWFISH`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php) method (as defined on the linked page), is a salted hash function with between 4 and 31 iterations on the hash. This is NOT a 2-way encryption function.

Comment: Is there any tutorial on how to use Suhosin for hashing?

Comment: @chnet Suhosin is a PHP patch - it just does some stuff that helps secure PHP. One of those things is adding support for CRYPT_BLOWFISH with PHP's `crypt()` function. It's not something you use to write applications. If you're on shared hosting, you probably won't be able to get it installed.

Comment: If you're not sure, I added something to the answer above to check if you can use CRYPT_BLOWFISH in your current configuration.

And to clarify, if you had Suhosin installed you could use the CRYPT_BLOWFISH hashing same as if you had PHP 5.3.0.

Answer (score 3):

PEAR's [Crypt_Blowfish](http://pear.php.net/package/Crypt_Blowfish/) package provides blowfish encryption using the mcrypt extension if it is available, and if not it implements the blowfish algorithm natively in php. It does not fall back to using any other form of encryption.

There is no "hand-written" documentation for the package though, there is [auto-generated API documentation](http://pear.php.net/package/Crypt_Blowfish/docs/latest/) derived from annotations in the package itself.

This is how I use it to encrypt:

```
$bf = Crypt_Blowfish::factory('ecb', null, null, CRYPT_BLOWFISH_PHP);
$iv = 'abc123+=';                                                      
$key = BLOWFISH_KEY;                                                   
$bf->setKey($key, $iv);                                                
$encrypted = bin2hex($bf->encrypt($password));
```

And to decrypt:

```
$bf = Crypt_Blowfish::factory('ecb', null, null, CRYPT_BLOWFISH_PHP);       
$iv = 'abc123+=';                                                              
$key = BLOWFISH_KEY;                                                           
$bf->setKey($key, $iv);                                                        
$decrypted = trim($bf->decrypt(hex2bin($password)));
```

Where BLOWFISH_KEY is a constant which I've defined elsewhere in the code.

In these examples I am explicitly using the PHP implementation.

If I wanted Crypt_Blowfish to decide which engine to use, i.e. to determine if it can use the mcrypt extension if it is available (and otherwise use the php implementation) then I'd change over with CRYPT_BLOWFISH_AUTO. To explicitly use the mcrypt extension, specify CRYPT_BLOWFISH_MCRYPT.