# Is this login system secure

Tags: php, mysql, security, authentication, sql-injection

Is this login system secure ?

```
    if ($_POST[$submit]){

$user = $_POST[$user];
$pass = $_POST[$pass];

if ($user && $pass){ //if user and pass is enterered

        require("vars.php"); //require MySQL conection settings
        mysql_connect($auth_mysql_server, $auth_mysql_user, $auth_mysql_pass); //connect to MySQL
        mysql_select_db($auth_mysql_db); // select MySQL database

        $pass = md5($pass); // hash password

        $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $auth_mysql_table WHERE user='$user'"); // run query
        $numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);

        if ($numrows == 1){ //check if user exists
            $row = mysql_fetch_assoc ($query);
            $dbid = $row[$auth_mysql_id_row];
                $dbuser = $row[$auth_mysql_user_row];
                $dbpass = $row[$auth_mysql_pass_row];

                if ($pass == $dbpass){ // if password is equal to the one in the database start session
                    session_start();
                    //set session information
                    $_SESSION['user'] = $dbuser;

                    header("Location:$auth_loggedin"); // goto logged in page

                }
                else return (3);
        }
        else return (2);

        mysql_close(); // close MySql connection
    }
    else return (1);}
```

If not how could i make it secure ?

I hashed the password but i know md5 can be decrypted however sha1 can be too.Also is the`mysql_close()` needed ?

Comment: look at `bcrypt` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6863410/php-bcrypt-hashing

Comment: Well, not since you posted it here, it isn't.

Comment: The `$user` variable needs to be escaped before being used in a query. Or your entire database can easily be deleted by SQL injcetions.

Comment: `$user` is passed plain... meaning someone could put in another code.  You should prepare that by escaping it or stripping out bad characters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

no it is not secure. you are opening yourself to sql-injection attacks. imagine what would happen, if somebody entered this into your user-input-field (which goes into the $_POST[$user])

```
a'; drop table user; select '1'='1
```

this would result in an sql statement like this:

```
SELECT * FROM $auth_mysql_table WHERE user='a'; drop table user; select '1'='1'
```

which you would execute against your database. that's bad!

you need to sanitize your input. read this: http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php

edit: [relevant](http://xkcd.com/327/)

Comment: I agree that is not secure, but `mysqli` would execute the statement that you reported, `mysql` wouldn't.  To inject with mysql you need to cause MySQL errors and use escape chars to have the output printed to screen.

Comment: wow, i did not realise how insecure it was. thanks for the great example

Comment: mysql_query() won't execute the second/third/... query. But even with only one query executed your code is vulnerable; at least for a mass-password-check-attack (there's probably a proper name for this kind of attack) - because the parameter isn't encoded properly and because you store plain text passwords one could add `OR passwordfield='somecommonpassword'` to the WHERE condition. Take a fairly large user base and a fairly common password - et voilà

Answer (score 5):

Add salt to your hashes. This can be a random string, a user's name, timestamp of account creation or pretty much whatever you like, as long as it's the same every time a given user logs in. The purpose is to first, break rainbow tables (long lists of common passwords that have been md5 encrypted) and second, add entropy to normally short passwords.

```
$pass = $_POST['pass'];
$salt = "7y9fhu8a"
$secure_pass = md5( $pass . $salt );
```

Secondly, you're not sanitizing your username input. You could add a mysql_real_escape_string to your username to prevent sql injection attacks.

```
$query = "SELECT * ".
         "FROM $auth_mysql_table ".
         "WHERE user='" . mysql_real_escape_string($user) . "'";
$result = mysql_query($query);
```

There are other ways to sanitize user input, but that's the quick and dirty. As far as the mysql_close goes, i wouldn't bother. If you need to run any other queries you'd need to reopen the connection.

Answer (score 0):

No it's not secure.

You need to sanitize your user inputs or (even better) use bind variables. For PHP you can use PDO: [PHP PDO prepared statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1457131/php-pdo-prepared-statements)

Also, an unsalted md5 is a **terrible** choice for hashing passwords and provides no real security. A salted md5 is only marginally better (but still in the terrible category).

You should either:

1. Not store any passwords- use federated login (OpenID, OAuth, etc)
2. If you are going to handle passwords yourself then use a **much** stronger hash function such as [scrypt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10149554/are-there-any-php-implementations-of-scrypt), [bcrypt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4795385/how-do-you-use-bcrypt-for-hashing-passwords-in-php), or [PBKDF2](http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash-pbkdf2.php).

Answer (score -1):

`mysql_close` is not needed but is good practice.  PHP will automatically close the connection at the end of the script.

MD5 is not the best encryption method, you can use some other PHP encryption library like AES

See this link for more information about PHP encryption:
http://php.net/manual/en/ref.mcrypt.php

keep in mind that you also have to ***ALWAYS sanitize*** the code !!

MySQL injection can be a bad beast!!

Comment: md5 and aes are not interchangeable, md5 is a hash algorithm while aes/Rijndael is a cipher.

Comment: Correct, but the conjunction of the two can be more secure.